# Importing sheet using JExcelApi

Tags: java, jexcelapi

Let me start by saying I'm very new to Java and to this site.  I've read a book or two now and since then have been looking for small projects to keep myself entertained.  I've tried to research this but I haven't been able to find the information I need.  With that said, this is my first question here so if this is very early beginner stuff and I'm missing something obvious I apologize.

Regarding the project, my brother-in-law has an issue at work where he has 90 or so Excel workbooks in a folder and he needs to merge the first worksheet of each report into one master workbook.  He can do it manually but I thought it would be interesting to try and figure out a way to do it with Java.

I did some research and downloaded the JExcelAPI and added the .jar to my classpath.  I've created two directories on my computer.

C:\Excel\

C:\Excel\Finished\

Inside C:\Excel\ I've created two dummy excel sheets.  I've renamed the first sheet on each for testing purposes.  In the finished folder I've created my master document that I intend to merge these sheets into.  When the sheets are empty and I run this the sheets appear to get copied over.  There are two sheets in the master file and their names correspond to the names I gave them in their respective workbooks so I assume this is working.  However, when I add information to one of these sheets and try to run this I get a null pointer exception.  I've been working on this for hours now so maybe I just need a break but I can't figure out what's wrong.  I went to the website for JExcelAPI and tried what looks like an outdated method for doing this (before importSheet() existed).  That didn't work either and also returned a null pointer exception.

If someone has time and is familiar with JExcelAPI, could you let me know what's wrong?  I would really appreciate it.  I've posted the error and my code below.

--Error--

```
spreadsheet1.xls
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at jxl.write.biff.SheetCopier.deepCopyCells(SheetCopier.java:996)
at jxl.write.biff.SheetCopier.importSheet(SheetCopier.java:542)
at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.importSheet(WritableSheetImpl.java:2699)
at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.importSheet(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:1897)
at sheetcopier.SheetCopier.main(SheetCopier.java:32)
```

--Code--

```
package sheetcopier;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import jxl.*;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;

public class SheetCopier {

public static void main(String[] args) throws WriteException, BiffException {
    Path inputpath = Paths.get("C:/Excel"); //Directory with excel documents to be copied
    File outputfile = new File("C:/ExcelFinished/finishedbook.xls"); //Master/End file

    //Read all files from directory
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> inputfiles = Files.newDirectoryStream(inputpath)){

        //Get a writable workbook
        WritableWorkbook writableworkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(outputfile);            

        for(Path path: inputfiles)
        {
            Workbook sourceworkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(path.toFile()); //Get the source workbook
            System.out.println(path.getFileName()); //Print workbook being processed
            Sheet readablesheet = sourceworkbook.getSheet(0); //Get the first sheet
            writableworkbook.importSheet(readablesheet.getName(), 0, readablesheet); //Import the sheet into the new workbook
            //Sheet names are imported if sheets are empty.  If sheets are populated I get a null pointer error.
        }

        writableworkbook.write();
        writableworkbook.close();
    }
    catch(NotDirectoryException e) {
        System.err.println(inputpath + " is not a directory." + e);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("I/O error." + e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What about using [`apache.poi`](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) Java API? [See](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JSF-Questions/22407-Convert-the-excel-sheet-data-into-oracle-table-through-java-or-jsp.html). Apache POI is a Java library for reading and writing various Microsoft file formats, especially Office related ones, based on OLE2 and OOXML, such as XLS and DOCX.

Comment: I saw that mentioned while researching.  From the comments I read it sounded like JExcepAPI was recommended for smaller projects like this since it's easier to use and understand.  The importSheet() method also seems to be exactly what I need so since I've already put the time into it I thought if someone here has some expertise I'd try that route first before apache.poi.  If there isn't an easy solution to this though I'll go that route.  Thank you for the prompt reply :)

Comment: one suggestion would be to go the other way.. Loop through each row and column, and add the values of the cells as a new sheet to the writableworkbook ...
apache poi is a very good alternative

Comment: I went and downloaded apache.poi and was able to find some code that uses it to copy a sheet.  I wrote the rest of what I needed to have it apply to many workbooks and it's behaving nicely.  Thank you everyone.  If someone reads this and is still able to tell me what my original problem was though I'd appreciate it.

Comment: So it's working. Very nice and best of luck. If you still have problems, please post them with your next question and you will be able to get help accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in jxl-2.6.12.jar, use jxl-2.6.10.jar instead.

Details:

typo '&&' into '&'

line 493 - line 504 in WritableSheetCopier.java

```
if (c != null)
          {
            toSheet.addCell(c);

            // Cell.setCellFeatures short circuits when the cell is copied,
            // so make sure the copy logic handles the validated cells        
            if (c.getCellFeatures() != null &
                c.getCellFeatures().hasDataValidation())
            {
              validatedCells.add(c);
            }
          }
```

line 540 - line 551 in WritableSheetCopier.java

```
if (c != null)
          {
            toSheet.addCell(c);

            // Cell.setCellFeatures short circuits when the cell is copied,
            // so make sure the copy logic handles the validated cells        
            if (c.getCellFeatures() != null &
                c.getCellFeatures().hasDataValidation())
            {
              validatedCells.add(c);
            } 
          }
```

line 990 - line 1001 in SheetCopier.java

```
if (c != null)
          {
            toSheet.addCell(c);

            // Cell.setCellFeatures short circuits when the cell is copied,
            // so make sure the copy logic handles the validated cells
            if (c.getCellFeatures() != null &
                c.getCellFeatures().hasDataValidation())
            {
              validatedCells.add(c);
            }
          }
```